# App crashing with NavigationView and CoordinatorLayout touch event

Tags: java, android

I have an app which uses a CoordinatorLayout and a NavigationDrawer. However, whenever I go to open the NavigationView (by swiping from edge of device screen), my app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.MotionEvent.getX()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:9409)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:449)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2373)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.cancelChildViewTouch(DrawerLayout.java:1668)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.peekDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1916)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback.access$000(DrawerLayout.java:1801)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback$1.run(DrawerLayout.java:1807)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I tried overriding the touch event methods:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but that didn't help. Is there anyway that I can fix this error?

All advice is appreciated

Comment: could you please post the full logcat...

Comment: @Lal that is the full logcat. The rest is just irrelevant logging I'm using to keep track of my background web scraping class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I was able to fix things by:

Overriding the methods shown in my question:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and setting an onTouchListener for my CoordinatorLayout:

```
coordinatorLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; //make sure to return true
        }
    });
```